# =0 command not found bash

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

```
grep "::=BEGIN" -q < /home/erawson/bin/HP/adaptec.mib
CHK= echo $?
if ($CHK = "0") ; then
echo "failed"
else    
     exit
fi
```

error is:

```
/home/erawson/bin/try1: line 10: =: command not found
```

Comment: Also, what's on line 10 in the file ? In the script you posted , I don't see anything having `=:` there

Comment: That's not how to format code (i've edited for you). http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/14089/186134

Comment: Do you want to print `failed` if the file matches or if the file doesn't match? Your code, if we fix the syntax errors, will print `failed` if the command succeeded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change if statement to `if [ $CHK -eq 0 ]; then`. Notice spaces between square braces.

Variable CHK also has to be assigned like so `CHK=$(echo $?)`.

Here's the script how it should look:

```
#!/bin/bash
grep "::=BEGIN" -q < testfile1.txt    
CHK="$?"
if [ "$CHK" -eq 0 ] ; then
        echo "failed"
else
    exit
fi
```

Comment: Tried  it with the spaces between square brackets. Now it gives error /home/erawson/bin/try1: line 10: [: -eq: unary operator expected

Comment: @user2446359 You've been missing some other things, too. I've edited the answer.

Comment: @user2446359 If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 3):

You have a few sytax errors there as has already been pointed out. You also seem to be using flawed logic. An exit status of `0` means the command succeeded, not that it failed. If what you want is to print `failed` if your file *doesn't* match the query string, all you need is:

```
grep -q "::=BEGIN" /home/erawson/bin/HP/adaptec.mib || echo "failed"
```

If you want to print `failed` if the file *matches* the string, use this:

```
grep -q "::=BEGIN" /home/erawson/bin/HP/adaptec.mib && echo "failed"
```

There's no need to save the exit status and no need for an if/else check.

Answer (score 2):

You just need an extra pair of parentheses:

```bsh
grep -q "::=BEGIN" </home/erawson/bin/HP/adaptec.mib
if (("$?" = "0")); then
    echo "failed"
else
    exit
fi
```

- The correct arithmetic operator syntax is `((`
- Also as you are just using the exit code `$?`, there is no need to save it in another variable, you can use it directly.

This can be further simplified as:

```bsh
if grep -q "::=BEGIN" </home/erawson/bin/HP/adaptec.mib; then
    echo "failed"
else
    exit
fi
```

Comment: The variable assignment must be CHK=$(echo $?), otherwise that does not get assigned

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, your requirement is, 
if you get output for grepping string "::=BEGIN", you want to echo "failed"..right??
And I'm not sure why you have used ";" after if...again used "then"

you may try the following

```
if [ -n `grep -q "::=BEGIN" /home/erawson/bin/HP/adaptec.mib` ]
then
        echo "failed"
else
        exit
fi
```

Hope this helps!! (according to my assumptions)

Comment: Note that you don't actually need the `-n`,  you can just do `if grep -q "::=BEGIN" file; then echo "failed"; else exit; fi`.